# Is it possible to download google's map for a particular location from own android app?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've used google's map in our android application which is working fine at the time of internet available. Now my clients want to download the particular location's map. The idea is it should work in the absence of internet.
Now my question is since the google map has the feature of map downloading, I also want to use that feature from my own app. So is it possible? if it is possible then refer some resources.
Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: yes is possible try google for this

Answer (score 1):

No you cant do that because it against Google policy. Only App GoogleMaps by Google can download offline map.
But you can use your own app to open App GoogleMaps and use offline area form it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to jump to Google map with coordinate from my own app. Work well with no internet and offline area.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=40.660977,-74.095616 (name of marker)"));
    //40.660977,-74.095616 is latitude and longitude you want to open.
startActivity(intent);
```